# Filter a string from html agility pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I grab html from a URL, then I select the element `table` and select all `tr` elements inside `table` that contain `tr` in their `id` attribute value. Now I have 20 or so elements like this:

`<th class="nw">1 Jan</th><td class="nw">Friday</td><td><a href="/holidays/andorra/new-year-day">New Year&#39;s Day</a></td><td>National holiday</td>`

How can I get each text **separately** from the element above?
Example output: `1 Jan/Friday/New Year's Day/National holiday`

```
var url = "https://www.timeanddate.com/holidays/andorra/";
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var a1 = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id","").Equals("holidays-table"))
    .ToList();

var a2 = a1[0].Descendants("tr")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("id","").Contains("tr"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
List<List<string>> holidays = document
    .DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//table[@id='holidays-table']/tbody/tr")
    .Select(tr => tr.ChildNodes
                    .Where(n => n.Name == "th" || n.Name == "td")
                    .Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim())
                    .ToList())
    .Where(row => row.Any())  // filter out empty rows
    .ToList();

foreach (var row in holidays)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row));
}
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0SADls